# Is it possible change file lines without detecting it by VCS?

Tags: svn, version-control, intellij-idea

It's quite common for me to have few changed lines in the file that should be not commited to VCS. For this situation I:

1. Shelf changes
2. Make commit/merge
3. Unshelf changes

Is is possible to simplify this workflow? May be it's possible to mark lines as "not commitable"?

Answer (score 0):

Put these changes in a separate changelist, like **Don't Commit**. Commit your default changelist or task specific changes as usual. IntelliJ IDEA will handle the rest.

If you enable an option to show **Update Project** dialog in `Version Control` | `Confirmations` , you'll see this:

[image: Update Project]

Clean options would depend on the VCS integration, for `git` there is support for stashing, for other VCS systems you may get only `Shelve` option.

This works per file, there is no option to ignore changes in the specific lines.